# PHP: Dividing timeframe into 3 equal parts

Tags: php, datetime

Please take a look at the following code:

```
$parts_count = 3;
$diff = strtotime('2013-11-30 00:00:00') - time();
$diff = $diff / $parts_count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $parts_count; $i++) {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', time() + $diff * ($i + 1) );
}
```

I am trying to divide the difference between the current time and a deadline (2013-11-30 00:00:00) into 3 equal parts.

The result I get is more than interesting though. It is:

```
2013-11-16 23:11:36
2013-11-23 11:11:48
2013-11-30 00:11:00
```

As you see, the latest deadline is 11 minutes past the original deadline, which is very weird. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad php date(); when using EasyPHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877189/bad-php-date-when-using-easyphp)

Answer (score 5):

Misspelling in format, should be:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + $diff * ($i + 1) );
```